# Creating a property class with no default value and with value

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to create a property class with a default value and no value. Is this right? If I want a property with no value I'll just call GameLevel class and if I want a property with default value I'll just call GameLevelWithDefaultValue

```
public abstract class GameLevel
{
    public abstract int nextLevelToUnlock { get; set; }

    public abstract List<LevelDetails> levelDetails { get; set; }
}

class GameLevelWithDefaultValue : GameLevel
{
    public override int nextLevelToUnlock { get; set; } = 1;

    public override List<LevelDetails> levelDetails { get; set; } = new List<LevelDetails>()
    {
        new LevelDetails{levelIndex = 1, Stars = 0 },
        new LevelDetails{levelIndex = 2, Stars = 0 },
        new LevelDetails{levelIndex = 3, Stars = 0 }
    };
}

public class LevelDetails
{
    public int levelIndex { get; set; }
    public int Stars { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't create objects of type `GameLevel`, since it's an `abstract` class.
I suggest you to have only the `GameLevel` class (not abstract) with its own properties and then setting the values using the constructor of the class, with the possibility to use the Builder pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something like this:

```
public class GameLevel
{
    public int NextLevelToUnlock { get; set; }
    public List<LevelDetails> LevelDetails { get; set; }

    public GameLevel() { }

    public GameLevel(int nextLevelToUnlock, List<LevelDetails> levelDetails)
    {
        NextLevelToUnlock = nextLevelToUnlock;
        LevelDetails = levelDetails;
    }
}

public class LevelDetails
{
    public int LevelIndex { get; set; }
    public int Stars { get; set; }

    public LevelDetails(int levelIndex, int stars)
    {
        LevelIndex = levelIndex;
        Stars = stars;
    }
}

public static class GameLevelBuilder
{
    public static GameLevel BuildGameLevelWithDefaultValue()
    {
        var defaultLevelDetail = new List<LevelDetails>()
        {
            new LevelDetails(1, 0),
            new LevelDetails(2, 0),
            new LevelDetails(3, 0)
        };

        return new GameLevel(1, defaultLevelDetail);
    }
}
```

When you need the object with the default value, you'll let the `GameLevelBuilder` create the object for you, while when you need the object without passing the initial values, you'll use the parameterless constructor of `GameLevel`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class. If you inherit an abstract class, you must override it's abstract properties. So, the value of `nextLevelToUnlock` and `levelDetails` depends on the child class.
Also, default value for class in C# is null, or the result of it's zero parameter constructor for value types. If you don't assign any value to a field, it will get it's default value.